# Send stream from VLC to ffserver

Tags: streaming, vlc-media-player, centos, ffmpeg

I want to send a stream from VLC on Windows to `ffserver` (as input stream for `ffmpeg`) on a CentOS virtual machine.

How can I do this?

Comment: You mean streaming a video from VLC and then **to** FFserver? FFserver is a streaming server itself so I guess it will only stream files, not other streams. I could be mistaken though.

Comment: Well I kind of need to do this: get a stream from a webcam. Send it to ffserver (the problem is that this one will be set on a centralized server at witch I don't have direct access after I configure it) then convert/whatever and stream it again to web. The part with the ffserver is fixed... can't change it. I accept any suggestion for the first part (send from webcam to ff).

Answer (score -1):

Why you don't use ffmpeg to send your stream? You can read any input stream using ffmpeg (more flexible than VLC); then feed it to ffserver using http. Maybe [this](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Streaming%20media%20with%20ffserver) help you.

Comment: Because those were the requirements at that point.